# Time constraint function in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

New column should have `yes` or `no`.

> If S1 before `6:30` and after `15:00` print `yes` OW `No`
>   If S2 before `14:30` and after `23:00` print `yes` OW `No`
>   If S3 before `22:30` and after `7:00` print `yes` OW `No`

Inputs are like below

```
Shift as per roster | In-Time (hh:mm)   | Out-Time (hh:mm)
--------------------+-------------------+--------------------
S1                  | 14:49             | 23:11
S1                  |                   |
S1                  |                   |
S2                  |                   |
WO                  |                   |
WO                  |                   |
S2                  |                   |
S2                  | 22:26             | 21:40
S2                  | 7:01              | 7:07
S2                  | 20:38             | 7:16
S2                  | 5:05              | 7:16
WO                  |                   |
WO                  | 14:28             | 21:41
S2                  | 14:27             | 23:09
S2                  | 14:09             | 23:06
S2                  |                   |
S2                  | 7:07              | 19:00
S2                  |                   |
WO                  | 22:27             | 22:30
WO                  | 7:09              | 22:22
CO                  | 7:08              | 7:09
S3                  |                   | 21:36
S3                  | 19:42             | 7:09
S3                  | 20:54             | 7:08
S3                  | 7:08              | 
WS2                 | 6:23              | 15:16
WS2                 | 6:27              | 15:26
WO                  | 6:22              | 15:10
WO                  |                   |
S2                  |                   |
S2                  |                   |
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new column use this formula :
(If 'shifts per area' is in B column, add this to 2nd row)

```
=IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(IF(B2="S1";"6:30";IF(B2="S2";"14:30";IF(B2="S3";"22:30"))))>C2;TIMEVALUE(IF(B2="S1";"15:00";IF(B2="S2";"23:00";IF(B2="S3";"07:30"))))<D2);"Yes";"No")
```

But this is very static, so I suggest you to Add another Sheet (like Sheet2) with your data:

**`[Sheet2]`** start data in `A1`

```
Shift | before Time | after Time
------+-------------+-------------------
 S1   | 6:30        | 15:00
 S2   | 14:30       | 23:00
 S3   | 22:30       | 7:00
```

And use this formula instead of previous :

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!A:C;2;FALSE)>C4;VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet!A:C;3;FALSE)<D4);"Yes";"No")
```